# How do I get simple user input with Struts?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I am trying to get user input in Struts using NetBeans 7.4. There are two .jsp files, welcomeStruts.jsp where the user enters text, and another one, index.jsp where this text should be displayed. The question is: which tag library do I need to use in order to process the user input? In Struts1, it worked when taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"  were set up and then processing the user input as something like this code:

Hello World, `<s:property value="name"/>`

It does not work in Struts2. What taglib do I include in Struts2? How do I get user input from welcomeStruts.jsp to be displayed in index.jsp? Thank you.

welcomeStruts:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>

<html:html lang="true">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title><bean:message key="welcome.title"/></title>
        <html:base/>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: white">

        <logic:notPresent name="org.apache.struts.action.MESSAGE" scope="application">
            <div  style="color: red">
               ERROR:  Application resources not loaded -- check servlet container
               logs for error messages.
            </div>
        </logic:notPresent>

        <h3><bean:message key="welcome.heading"/></h3>
        <p><bean:message key="welcome.message"/></p>

        <p>Hello! This is the test welcome page for a Struts Web MVC project.</p>

        <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1> 

        <form action="hello"> 
            <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/> 
            <input type="text" name="name"/> 
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html:html>
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-nested" prefix="f" %>

<html>
<body> 

    <H3>Welcome <html:text property="name"/>!</H3>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't work because it's Struts 1 code. Migration from Struts1 code is not a simple task, and you have to rewrite your JSPs. Struts2 tags has different notation. However, JSTL and plain html still work.

Answer (score 0):

The taglib is `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>`
You have to write something like this:

```
    <s:form action="sendMsg">
<s:textfield name="msg" label="Insert message"/>
<s:submit/>
```

This is the `web.xml` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
      </filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <session-config>  
        <session-timeout>  
            600  
        </session-timeout>  
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

This is the `struts.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
   <package name="model" extends="struts-default">
   <action name="sendMsg" class="model.Test" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/yourPage.jsp</result>
      </action>
     </package>
</struts>
```

This is your class:

```
public class Test{
    private String msg;
    public Test() { }
    public String execute(){
        return "success";
    }
    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

}
```

Now add this in your page to show the

```
<s:property value="msg"/>
```

And don't forget to add the jar files for struts2

Comment: I wanted to say that getting simple user input with Struts won't be simple, but your answer says it much better!

Comment: `FilterDispatcher` is deprecated.

Comment: Exactly @AleksandrM  Use this filter instead
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>